# How to mitigate the hierarchical error propagation in tree-structured classification

Tags: machine-learning, svm, multiclass-classification, hierarchical-data-format

Suppose we have a multi-class classification problem, where the number of classes $K \geq 3$

We use a tree structure of multiple SVMs to divide and conquer the problem, with one example in the figure below.

[image: example tree structure]

Generally, in this kind of hierarchical classification, if a sample is wrongly classified in an upper layer, it is less likely to be corrected again in lower layers.

My question: Is there any strategy to mitigate such hierarchical error propagation in tree-structured classification?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question. Have you tried weighting the loss by the size of the tree below it?

Comment: No, I haven't tried that. Could you please tell me more about how to do it?